# what is the meaning of perforation here?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

"After the test is over , at the **perforation** point , tear the OMR answer sheet , hand over the original  OMR answer sheet to the invigilator  and retain the carbonless copy for your record."

I can not understand what  the meaning of perforation is here. As far as I know perforation means hole.

Can anyone please help me to understand the meaning of the whole sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is  the definition of PERFORATION from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
'one of the series of holes (as between rows of postage stamps) in a sheet that serve as an aid in separation'.
This is the meaning of the word used in the context.
The meaning of the sentence is:
"After finishing the test, tear off the answer sheet at the point of the holes, hand over the original answer sheet to the examiner assistant and keep the copy for your record.

Comment: You might like to also address why *point* seems to work in this context when *line* might be a more descriptive in a literal sense.